# Over a dozen git branches deleted, almost no space saved

Tags: git, branch

I deleted several old local branches (over half of the existing branches) from a half dozen Git repos I use. My purpose was to reduce the collective size of the repos, because every week I have to move them from my office computer to my laptop and back.

I checked the aggregate size of the parent directory in Windows Explorer. Before I pruned the old branches: 1,809,407,125 bytes. After: 1,809,394,136 bytes. By pruning about two dozen branches from six repos, I saved a grand total of 12,989 bytes.

Whatever changes the deleted branches represented, they were the work of two teams of engineers over the past several months. It's hard to believe that the deltas amounted to no more than 13 KB.

Is there something more that I must do to make Git reduce the amount of space a local repo occupies to match the amount of data it contains?

Comment: `git gc` to garbage collect the dead parts. But make sure you're not going to need them.

Answer (score 2):

To reduce the size of your git repo you might want to look at [git gc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc). It does housekeeping tasks that help reduce disk size and increase performance.

You may try:

```
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

Now about the branches.
A git branch is basically a pointer to a commit, deleting it doesn't necessarily deletes the commit objects (check [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is) for a better explanation on what git branches are).
Using git gc after removing your old branches will help remove unreachable objects that remained and you will probably see a bigger reduction on your repo size.